# inner join query with cross join issue

Tags: sql

I've got these tables in my database:

**Tourist** - this is the first table

```
 Tourist_ID - primary key
    name...etc...
```

**Extra_charges**

```
Extra_Charge_ID - primary key 
Extra_Charge_Description
Amount
```

**Tourist_Extra_Charges**

```
Tourist_Extra_Charge_ID


    Extra_Charge_ID - foreign key
        Tourist_ID - foreign key
```

I made a query so I can take the name of the Tourist and all the charges in EXTRA_CHARGES table **that doesn't belong to this tourist**.

```
SELECT  Tourist.Name,
        EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_Description,
        EXTRA_CHARGES.Amount 
FROM    Tourist
        CROSS JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES
WHERE   Tourist.Tourist_ID= 86 
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES
            WHERE   TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID = Tourist.Tourist_ID
            AND     TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID
        );
```

So the problem is that if the tourist has all extra_charges - my query will return no rows. 
But I need the name of the tourist no matter if he has or not extra_charges. But in my case I can't use left join instead of cross

Comment: Why can't you use left join? That seems like an artificial requirement. Also, please tag this question with the brand of SQL database you use, e.g. sql-server, mysql, oracle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two criteria you are applying are logically different, you need to use two queries to get it. The first is as before, the extra charges that a tourist does not have, and the second is for tourists who have all extra charges

```
SELECT  Tourist.Name,
        EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_Description,
        EXTRA_CHARGES.Amount 
FROM    Tourist
        CROSS JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES
        LEFT JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES
            ON TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID = Tourist.Tourist_ID
            AND TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID
WHERE   Tourist.Tourist_ID = 1 
AND     TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_Extra_Charge_ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT  Tourist.Name,
        NULL,
        NULL
FROM    Tourist
        CROSS JOIN EXTRA_CHARGES
        LEFT JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES
            ON TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID = Tourist.Tourist_ID
            AND TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID
WHERE   Tourist.Tourist_ID = 1 
GROUP BY Tourist.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_Extra_Charge_ID);
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28665/7)**